# Multiplying Matrices Together

Tags: c

I'm wondering where I've gone wrong here. There following is my matrix multiplication function.

```
void matMul(Matrix A, Matrix B, int ARows, int ACols, int BCols, Matrix C){
int x,y,z;
for(x=0; x<ARows; x++){
    for(y=0; y<BCols; y++){
        for(z=0; z<ACols; z++){
            C[x][y]+=(A[x][z])*(B[z][y]);
        }
    }
}
} /* matMul */
```

However, it is not doing its job of multiplying matrices together. Can Anyone spot where I seemed to have messed up?

Comment: Did you intialized C with 0 entries?

Comment: That I did not, lemme try that.
EDIT: THAT WORKED! Thanks :D. Silly mistake on my part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have entries of `C` be set to 0. Either you do this when you initialize the object or, if it is too expensive to do that there (in terms of code) you move them to the matrix multiplication:

```
void matMul(Matrix A, Matrix B, int ARows, int ACols, int BCols, Matrix C){
int x,y,z;
for(x=0; x<ARows; x++){
    for(y=0; y<BCols; y++){
        C[x][y] = 0;
        for(z=0; z<ACols; z++){
            C[x][y]+=(A[x][z])*(B[z][y]);
        }
    }
}
} /* matMul */
```

Comment: Yup, Thats exactly what I did when you told me to initialize them. Thank you sir :)